# authlib.jose.errors.InvalidClaimError: invalid_claim: Invalid claim "iss"

Tags: authlib

I'm building an oauth2 client with Flask and Authlib. My code to register the oauth is:

```py
google = oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id='',
    client_secret="",
    access_token_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    access_token_params=None,
    authorize_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/",
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email'},
    server_metadata_url="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
)
```

And my /authorize endpoint looks like this:

```py
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    token = google.authorize_access_token()
    resp = google.get('userinfo')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    userinfo = resp.json()
    
    return str(userinfo)
```

But I am getting the error

```
authlib.jose.errors.InvalidClaimError: invalid_claim: Invalid claim "iss"
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and removing the openid value from scope fixed it. I guess my google config didn't accomodate it,

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it, while keeping `openid` in the scope, by removing `access_token_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"` and `authorize_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"`

```py
    oauth = OAuth()
    oauth.register(
        name="google",
        server_metadata_url="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email profile"},
        client_id=settings.google_client_id,
        client_secret=settings.google_client_secret,
    )
```